# How to free IntPtr in C#?

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

How to free ptrSentFromPinvokedDLL?

```
IntPtr ptrSentFromPinvokedDLL= IntPtr.Zero;

int resultFromVendor = CallVendorDll(ref ptrSentFromPinvokedDLL);

resultFromVendor = DoMoreWorkFromVendorDLL(
    ptrSentFromPinvokedDLL, "workonthis");

// Free ptrSentFromPinvokedDLLhere
```

Comment: Well, how did the vendor *allocate* the pointer? Use the corresponding deallocator.

Comment: Presuming you even need to free it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ideally either the vendor worries about this or there would be a vendor function for deallocating the memory. If not, you need to know how the vendor allocated the memory. For example, if the vendor allocated the memory using [`LocalAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366723(VS.85).aspx) in `kernel32.dll` then you could free the memory using [`Marshal.FreeHGlobal(IntPtr)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx). Similarly, if the COM memory allocator [`CoTaskMemAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692727(VS.85).aspx) was used then [`Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(IntPtr)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freecotaskmem.aspx) would be used to free the memory. So check the documentation and proceed accordingly.

For reference, here's a nice [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366533(VS.85).aspx) about memory allocation models.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of knowing how to free it or if it even needs to be freed without seeing the code inside `CallVendorDll`. (Or some documentation)