# window handle from dllimport (do I need to dealocate memory)

Tags: c#, memory

I am using a window handle from a user32 dll -

```
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern
        bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Some where in my code I write below piece of code to bring the UI to foreground.

```
        IntPtr hWnd = _processes[n].MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
```

now, I see IntPtr is a pointer here. Do I need to write something to dealocate the memory?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299528/c-sharp-deallocate-memory-referenced-by-intptr

Comment: You don't have to, because you didn't allocate that memory in this case.

Comment: There is no "memory" being used.  You don't deallocate hWnd either, it is not your window.  Windows get destroyed when the user or the program closes them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply...I got it..